# Remover carácter para buscar no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou com problemas ao criar uma *function* para fazer uma busca no banco de dados e a partir do cep completar os campos relacionados a ele, como endereço, bairro, cidade e estado.

**Obs**: Possuo uma máscara no campo *cep*

**function.php**

```
<?php include("conn.php");

  /* Inicio da função para retornar campos a partir do CEP  GLOBAL */

       function cep($cep, $conn){
          $result = "SELECT * FROM cadcep WHERE cep = '$b_cep' LIMIT 1";
          $resultado = $conn->query($result);

          if($resultado){

              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
              $valores['tipo_logr'] = $row['tipo_logr'];
              $valores['nome_logr'] = $row['nome_logr'];
              $valores['bairro'] = $row['bairro'];
              $valores['cidade'] = $row['cidade'];
              $valores['estado'] = $row['estado'];


          } else {
              return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
          }

              return json_encode($valores);

      }


      if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
              echo cep($_GET['cep'], $conn);
      }
   /* Fim da função para retornar campos a partir do CEP GLOBAL */

?>
```

**JS para busca a partir de CEP**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#cep").on("change", function(){

               var $tipo_logr = $("select[name='tipo_logr']");
               var $nome_logr = $("input[name='nome_logr']"); 
               var $bairro = $("input[name='bairro']"); 
               var $cidade = $("input[name='cidade']"); 
               var $estado = $("input[name='uf']");

               $.getJSON('function_cep.php',{ 
                       cep: $( this ).val() 
               },function( json ){
                       $tipo_logr.val ( json.tipo_logr );
                       $nome_logr.val ( json.nome_logr );
                       $bairro.val ( json.bairro );
                       $cidade.val ( json.cidade );
                       $estado.val ( json.estado );

               });
       });
});
```

Comment: voce esta errando na function vou criar a resposta

Comment: eu possuo uma máscara, preciso retirar ela e depois efetuar a busca

Comment: é necessário adicionar a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare que criei comentários para ajudar no entendimento da resposta. criei um array para não ter problemas no retorno, e no início da function utilizei replace para remover caracter, pode utilizar isso para outras situações, basta utilizar desta forma

```
function cep($cep, $conn){
   $chars = array(".","/","-","(", ")");
   $b_cep = str_replace($chars, "", $a_cep);
```

Agora código completo solucionando seu problema

```
<?php include("conn.php");

/* Inicio da função para retornar campos a partir do CEP  GLOBAL */
    function cep($cep, $conn){
        /* Inicio removendo caracteres da mascara do campo cep para efetuar busca no banco de dados */
        $a_cep = str_replace(".", "", $cep);
        $b_cep = str_replace("-", "", $a_cep);
        /* Fim Removendo caracteres da mascara do campo cep para efetuar busca no banco de dados */
        $result = "SELECT * FROM cadcep WHERE cep = '$b_cep' LIMIT 1";

        $resultado = $conn->query($result);

        // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
        $valores = array();

        if($resultado){

            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
            $valores['tipo_logr'] = $row['tipo_logr'];
            $valores['nome_logr'] = $row['nome_logr'];
            $valores['bairro'] = $row['bairro'];
            $valores['cidade'] = $row['cidade'];
            $valores['estado'] = $row['estado'];


        } else {
            return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
        }

            return json_encode($valores);

    }


    if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
            echo cep($_GET['cep'], $conn);
    }
/* Fim da função para retornar campos a partir do CEP GLOBAL */

?>
```

Comment: obrigado funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: A resposta é valida e funciona, porém seria melhor retirar tudo que for diferente de dígitos da variável  ficaria mais confiável para mandar para o banco de dados. Porém dessa maneira atende a necessidade do @Victor T.

Comment: como eu disse no início da reposta, basta ele alterar o str_replace, para eliminar os caracteres desejados  desta forma => $chars = array(".","/","-","(", ")"); $tb_cep = str_replace($chars, "", $a_cep) vou editar a resposta

Comment: Mesmo assim continua inviável a partir do momento que você pode trabalhar com Regex, muito trabalho ficar alimentando uma variável com o que você não quer. nesse caso ele só quer números muito mais fácil um método que retorne apenas isso, imagina é inputado 1 "A" nessa variável ela vai passar, ele vai ter que fazer um build apenas para adicionar o "A" na variável de rejeição?

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma:

```
$.getJSON('function_cep.php?cep=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie um método que retorne para você apenas dígitos com `Regex` para melhor legibilidade, digo para criar um método porque você pode precisar em outros lugares, adicione em uma classe `Helper` ou qualquer outra que você armazene seus métodos de ajuda:

```
function apenasDigitos($value)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$value);
}
```

Sendo assim antes de enviar o campo CEP para o banco de dados chame esse método.
na sua variável `$b_cep`, ficando dessa maneira:

```
$b_cep = apenasDigitos($b_cep);
```

Sua variável agora não terá nada além de números podendo assim seguir em frente e fazer a consulta no banco de dados.